# how can i fix class "db" not found error?

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to PHP. Been trying out for weeks but there is no progress at all. I have 2 files, DB.php, index.php.

On index.php, I am trying to get an instance of PDO to connect to database but unable to do so. It keeps telling me that the class DB is not found

Here is the code,

in index.php

```
require_once('core/init.php');

<?
DB::getInstance();
?>
```

In DB.php,

```
<?
class DB
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newtry', 'root', '');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die($e->getMessage());

        }

    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new DB();

        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }   
}

?>
```

in init.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql'=> array(
        'host'=> '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'newtry'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expire' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'

    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'libraries/'.$class.'.php';

});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

?>
```

Comment: You do not include your `DB.php` file

Comment: Is your DB.php file in the libraries directory as it's expected to be by `spl_autoload_register()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `require_once` is outside of what would be your php tags, which are wrong by the way. try something like this:

```php
<?php
require_once('core/init.php');

DB::getInstance();
?>
```

Samething with your `DB` file, the tags needs to be `<?php` rather than `<?`.
You also never seams to import your DB file in any other file. you could try to import it directly like so.

```
<?php 
require_once('db.php');
DB::getInstance();
```

Comment: thank you so much, i guess it was a mistake of teh syntax error on my part and certainly did not notice that and will look out for it onwards